# I'd like to paint a certain number of highlights under the check box

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

[image]

Like the above image, if you fill in the number at the top and check the check box below, I want to put the background color in the cell below. I think we can use the conditional form, is there a way?

I used the countifs function, but I don't know which factor to put.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually GoogleSheets, which is different to Excel. One option I could think of was to use `OFFSET()` which is volatile by nature, but so is conditional formatting:

[image]

Custom formula for the range `A2:C10`:

```
=OR(MAP(SEQUENCE(A$1,1,-1,-1),LAMBDA(x,LET(y,OFFSET(A2,x,0),IFERROR(ISNUMBER(-y)*NOT(ISNUMBER(y))*y*NOT(A2),0)))))
```

**Note:** Remove `NOT(A2)` if you wish to color the cells below even if they are marked themselves:

[image]

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906976299560615966/1098517924173582539/image.png
Applies normally. However, when applied to Y19 lines like the corresponding image, the top two rows become empty. How can I solve this?

Comment: I hope you made the appropriate changes to the references inside the formula? @onedayharu

Comment: The reference I changed is as follows.=OR(MAP(SEQUENCE(Y$19,1,-1,-1),LAMBDA(x,LET(y,IFERROR(OFFSET(Y20,x,0),0),y*NOT(ISNUMBER(y))))))

Comment: Worked fine for me, see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6u6g.png). My formula: `=OR(MAP(SEQUENCE(Y$19,1,-1,-1),LAMBDA(x,LET(y,IFERROR(OFFSET(Y20,x,0),0),y*NOT(ISNUMBER(y))*NOT(Y20)))))`

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/906976299560615966/1098525690523033720/image.png
This happens when a letter is placed on a row with a number.